# HttpHandler with Flash file upload question

Tags: httphandler

I have a flash file uploader that allows uploading multiple files in one shot.
Now on one click how many times will the hanlder is supposed to be called?

I am seeing that the ProcessRequest() of the HttpHandler is getting called for each of the files I upload. If I upload 5 files, then the Process request gets called 5 times.

This seems odd. I would expect the handler to be called just once where I will loop the

Can anyone confirm this behavior or I am missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Flash uploader and the ASP.Net HTTPHandler are not related.  If the Flash uploader calls the HTTPHandler 5 times, you will see ProcessRequest() called 5 times.

If the Flash uploader serializes the data, and passes the entire string to the HTTPHandler for deserialization and processing, you will see ProcessRequest() called once.